# Send a JSON through Django REST Framework

Tags: reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am getting started with the Django rest framework and I encountered a problem that I am still not able to solve.

Here is the problem:

I want to create a tech store website. Using the API that the manufacturing company provides, I will upload the products on my website.
The manufacturing company uses XML, and the result of the API is XML.
Using python I converted the XML output from the API to JSON.

Here is the code for that:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import json

url = 'https://www.parterURLProductsInStock.asmx'
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
raw_data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetCTProducts xmlns="http://www.partnerURL.com/B2B">
      <username>username</username>
      <password>psw</password>
    </GetCTProducts>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

x = requests.post(url, data=raw_data, headers=headers)
js = xmltodict.parse(x.text)
print(json.dumps(js))
```

For my website, I want to use Django and React. So in order to get the products in the frontend, I need an API, and in most cases, Django REST Framework is used.

I know that with the Django REST Framework we can convert classes from modules.py into JSON and send it to the front using serializers. But how can I send the data (JSON) that is stored in my `js` variable?

If anyone can helo me that would be really helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response` class from rest_framework to return a json like this :

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view()  # Only GET method
def get_js(request):
    # ...
    x = requests.post(url, data=raw_data, headers=headers)
    js = xmltodict.parse(x.text)
    
    return Response(js)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I implemented this part, but how can I show it for example in http:localhost/api/product ?

Comment: You want to display the result on a page ? Or return a json response ?

Comment: I have a JSON stored in the variable js , and now i want to use django to send this json so that i can get the results from my frontend, from react